# How to fix text spacing issues?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am having a bug where in the editor console my text looks fine.

Text in the inspector:
[image]

Text in the game:
[image]

See how the text is squishing and stretching.  How do I fix this and where is it coming from?

Canvas Image
[image]

Comment: It almost looks like two separate fonts are being used. You'll have to give us some more information.

Comment: "in-game" is in unity editor on play? or on target platform (which)? It indeed looks like different fonts

Comment: in-game is on my phone (Android).  - I am using the default font in the Inspector (Arial)

Comment: are you using some canvas resolution trickery?

Comment: I don't believe so.  What would I need to look at to see if that is happening?

Comment: If the text is displayed on a canvas, look at the canvas properties. You'll see if something is up there. Also, is that a blur effect gone missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [manual](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Font.html):

> The default font asset is a dynamic font which is set up to use Arial. If Unity can’t find the Arial font on your computer (for example, if you don’t have it installed), it will fall back to a font bundled with Unity called Liberation Sans.

The font in your second image is Liberation Sans, which indicates that you're seeing this fallback behavior.

Using the default font is fine for dev builds, but if you want a polished and consistent look then I would highly recommend importing a specific font. Unity has native support for TTF and OTF files.

If you don't want to do that, you could adjust the text object's kerning setting, which controls spacing between characters.

Comment: Oh awesome!  Ok I will try that.